# Save image with Mechanize and Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize and Nokogiri to gather some data. I need to save a picture that's randomly generated at each request.

In my attempt I'm forced to download all pictures, but the only one I really want is the image located within `div#specific`.

In addition, is it possible to generate Base64 data from it, without saving it, or reloading its source?

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'nokogiri'

a = Mechanize.new { |agent|
    agent.keep_alive = true
    agent.max_history = 0
}

urls = Array.new()
urls.push('http://www.domain.com');

urls.each {|url|

    page = a.get(url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page.body)

    if doc.at_css('#specific')

        page.images.each do |img|
          img.fetch.save('picture.png')
        end

    end
}
```

Comment: Hopefully this is not an attempt to defeat a CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 26):

To fetch the images from the specific location:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.domain.com')
images = page.search("#specific img")
```

To save the image:

```
agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"]).save "path/to/folder/image_name.jpg"
```

To get image encoded without saving:

```
encoded_image = Base64.encode64 agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"]).body_io.string
```

I ran this just to make sure that the image that was encoded can be decoded back:

```
File.open("images/image_name.jpg", "wb") {|f| f.write(Base64.decode64(encoded_image))}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken saving the image this way reloads the src? I NEED to save the image, or get base64, WITHOUT reloading the src.

Comment: No reloading happens. Unlike an internet browser, Mechanize does not automatically download images or any other assets. It only loads the html document. Then you find the necessary image url in the document and explicitly download the image.

Comment: Is there ANY way of doing it, without reloading the image? Perhaps using another gem?

Comment: @charliexx I think you are misunderstanding how Mechanize, and browsers in general, work. victmask is correct.

Comment: Thank you so much for this ;) I'd like to use the enocoding you showed for saving the images in mongodb. Any tips for a better solution maybe?