# Get captcha image using mechanize in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mechanize, captcha

I'm using mechanize to fill a booking form on the behalf of my user. The form has a captcha image. Using mechanize I can get the link to the image, but it's different all the time I access that link. Therefore, the captcha image I put in front of my user (so he can fill it and submit the form) is not the one required by the original form and the booking doesn't work.

Here is my controller code:

```
booking_page = agent.get('https://my_website.com')
images = booking_page.search("#Captcha img")
@captcha = agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"])
```

And this in my view:

```
<%= image_tag @captcha.uri %>
```

A Captcha code is displayed but this is not the good one (the page has been refreshed). I also tried doing this following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861287/save-image-with-mechanize-and-nokogiri) :

Controller:

```
@encoded_image = Base64.encode64 agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"]).body_io.string
```

View:

```
<%= image_tag "data:image/jpeg;base64,#{@encoded_image}" %>
```

Same here, a captcha image is displayed but that's not the good one. The only way I managed to make a booking work is by saving the image on my computer.

```
agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"]).save "captcha.jpg"
```

What can I do to make it work for my user? Should I make them download the image (temp folder or equivalent) and then display it in the app? Is there any way to save the right image into a variable so I can use it in the view?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: My advice is to try to figure out where it's going wrong. Use pry-remote to set up some breakpoints where you can inspect things.

Comment: Thanks @pguardiario but I already figured it out. I get the source URL of the picture but when I call it it refreshes the page and I got the wrong captcha code extracted. Isn't my question clear enough?

Comment: Well it's clear that you're having problems but it's not clear at which point things go bad.

Comment: I just edited my question, hope this is better

Comment: In other words it's not clear if you're: not targeting the correct image, not downloading it properly, or not displaying it properly in the view. You need to narrow that down and pry-remote is the right tool to do that.

Comment: Maybe the problem is when you do `agent.get(images.first.attributes["src"])`. I believe this fires up a request to and changes the image like you said. You can try to not fire the `get` request, just scrape the image link, then put the src in a `image_tag` in your view.

Comment: @MurifoX thanks, but when I put the source in an image_tag, it does a new call on the desired url so I get a brand new captcha image :(