# Rails based Image Scraper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, scrape

I'm learning rails and would like to make an image scraper for 4chan. I don't really know where to start though, so I was wondering if anyone could point me towards anything that I could look into to make this happen or anything I could study to become familiar with image scraping.

Comment: use mechanize available here: https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize and check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14861287/save-image-with-mechanize-and-nokogiri

Answer (score 1):

Well, first  of all, you don't need to make a Rails App only for this image-scraping functionality. You could just write a script that does this. For that I would suggest using [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/). You then need to find the way 4chan displays images on it's pages  (inspecting the page from your browser), how are they structured in order to be able to get to them.

Comment: I'm using this to learn rails, I'm just wanting to learn it. I'll read up on Nokogiri, would that help me understand posting structures? I'm not sure what that means exactly, what I should be looking for in the code.

Comment: You need to find where the images are nested inside the page structure.

Comment: Ok got it. Thanks for the help